# Chrome developer tools . checking out responsive / different devise views leads to random results. Why?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Im using chrome developer tools to check out different device views (iPhone, iPad etc). I don't change the code, go on iPhone view etc and it all looks good. Then without changing the code, I check out the norebootview and go back to lets say iPhone or iPad view and everything looks very different. For example the margins are totally mixed up. Then when I refresh the page or go back to normal view back and forth, it looks normal again and sometimes it doesn't. I don't understand when that randomness comes from. I am using less/sass for the css.

Any suggestion would be really helpful!! Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a good practice to always perform a refresh when you change the device.

Comment: I do and sometimes it goes back to normal and sometimes it doesn't. I never had that problem and just don't understand the randomness of it. What happened just now for example is that the view doesn't show the whole iPhone (for example) devise width. So it looks like the margin is changed but it actually isn't. Maybe something is wrong with the fit to window view but Im not sure how to change it